# Does kubernetes-event-exporter support ipv6?

Tags: kubernetes, events, exporter

We are using kubernetes event export https://github.com/resmoio/kubernetes-event-exporter to send syslog messages, it works when the receivers.syslog.address is "IPv4address:port", but does not work with "[IPv6address]:port"

Does anyone know if this utility supports sending syslog messages to an IPv6 syslog receiver? And if so, how can I config it.

We tried the following config and it didn't work:

```
    receivers:
      - name: "syslog"
        syslog:
          network: "tcp"
          address: "[xxxx:xxx:xxx:x:1:2:3:1234]:1234"
          tag: "k8s.event"
```

Thanks in advance.